# Проблема в производительности репликации MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Проблема в производительности репликации `MySQL master-master`.

Запрос из веб-приложения выполняет серию операций `SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT` без репликации за `300-400 мс`. С включенной репликацией `1200-1400 мс`, что уже критично для пользователей.Если отключить репликацию, то приложение работает отлично.

Виртуальные машины крутятся на `SSD`.

Пытались изменить параметры `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0` (в `my.ini`) - безрезультатно.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В тормознутости ваших запросов? Пробовали искать способы их оптимизации и уменьшения их количества? Для insert/update используются транзакции?

Comment: Репликация требует записи бинлога, а дисковые операции прожорливы.